# How to read domain name information?

Tags: windows, ui-automation, autoit

I need to read domain name information from sysdm.cpl using AutoIt. I am able to launch the console.

Class value for the domain info (obtained using [AutoIt Window Information Tool](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm)) is `#32770`.

```
Run("control.exe sysdm.cpl,,4")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried searching for the domain name in the registry to see what key it's under, or if it is?

Comment: `ConsoleWrite(EnvGet("USERDNSDOMAIN")&@crlf)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for domain and for workgroup too:

```
Local $oWinNT = ObjGet("WinNT:")
For $oDomain In $oWinNT
    ConsoleWrite($oDomain.Name & @CRLF)
Next
```

I've found a more detailed (and faster) solution that uses the [WinAPI NetGetJoinInformation](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/173768-find-out-computer-domain-from-local-account/?do=findComment&comment=1257056).